# Keeping an SSH tunnel up while my system is up - init.d service or something else?

Tags: services, ssh-tunneling

I use an SSH tunnel on my host computer daily; but so far I've just been manually using some terminal just for that: Entering

```
ssh -D 5001 user@some.where.com
```

at the command line, and redoing it if the connection breaks. I want to arrange for this to happen automagically, on system startup, and for the tunnel to be recreated if it collapses (with some sort of exponential backoff on repeated failure). I was thinking of writing my own init.d script, but maybe there's already a mechanism in place on Linux systems for doing this that I'm disregarding. Or - maybe there's a more "appropriate" way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at autossh. It has support to reconnect lost tunnels. I will leave a link. The article suggests placing it in /etc/rc.local which is what I would do in Debian.

http://linuxaria.com/howto/permanent-ssh-tunnels-with-autossh